# 12031 Unkown error

Tags: jquery, web-services

I am trying to call a web service through jquery ajax method.

my client side code:

```
function FillMailToNames() {
        var empName = $('#<%= tbMailTo.ClientID %>').val();


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ContractEntry.aspx/GetEmployeesList",
                data: '{ name:'+ empName +'}',
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                processData: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $(data.d).each(function (index, item) {
                        var obj = {};

                        obj["caption"] = item.Name;
                        obj["value"] = item.Id.toString();
                        myArray.push(obj);

                    });

                    $('#<%= tbMailTo.ClientID %>').multiselect({ completions: myArray, enable_new_options: false, max_complete_results: 10, complex_search: false });
                },
                error: AjaxFailed
            });
    }
```

And my web method is :

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static List<NameId> GetEmployeesList(string name)
{
    List<NameId> lstEmplyeeNames = new AuthorizationController().GetEmployeesList(name);
    return lstEmplyeeNames;
}
```

I am calling this method on document.ready(), and i get error saying "12031 unkown". If I dont try to pass anything and call method without parameter my code works fine. When I try to call method with parameter then only I get this issue.
Please help to resolve.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are using `POST` to send your request. However you have defined `UseHttpGet = true` so you should switch your request to GET too.

Comment: check you `empName` by doing an alert or console log